# MVC5 application with areas and subfolders within the controller folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Back Story:
My company has several large, separate applications that we are consolidating into 1 application. While researching, I have gone with an MVC application and each application will be in the areas folder. So the structure is

- Application

  - Area

    - Application 1

      - Controllers

        - WorkWithReceipts

          - ReceiptsController
          - SomethingElseController
        - FileMaintenance

          - MainSetupController
    - Application 2

      - Controllers

        - Grass

          - TreesController
        - Trees

          - TreesController

**Problem**
So the problem I'm having is with my routing. It is always using the top one and, if I try to access MainSetupController, it searches for Controllers/WorkWithReceipts/MainSetup/[action] which breaks because it is under the FileMaintenance folder.

Here is my routing config.

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "FileMaintenance",
            "Accounting/FileMaintenance/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Courts.Areas.Accounting.Controllers.FileMaintenance" }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Receipts",
            "Accounting/Receipts/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Courts.Areas.Accounting.Controllers.Receipts" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Accounting",
            "Accounting/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Courts.Areas.Accounting.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

**QUESTION** 
So I am wondering if there is a way to set my routes up so that my routes expect the same parameters, but, depending on the area, controller, and action passed in, it finds the correct route to use. Right now it is always using the top most route.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'll try to cover the bases. If your problem is with generating the right URL with something like `Html.ActionLink`, you need to pass your `Area` as route param. For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Foo", "FooAction", "FooController", new { Area = "FooArea" })
```

Next, the namespace helps to restrict a particular route to an area/controller, etc., but it doesn't work in reverse. That is to say, an attempt to resolve the URL for something like `Url.Action("Index", "Foo", new { Area = "Bar" })` will never result in `Accounting/FileMaintenance/Foo/Bar/1` because that route has been restricted to the `Courts.Areas.Accounting.Controllers.FileMaintenance` namespace, *but*, a request for `Accounting/FileMaintenance/Foo/Bar/1` directly, will not necessarily resolve to that particular route if another route higher in the food chain matches first.

Comment: My apologies on it not being clear. I am wondering how to set my routes up so that my routes expect the same parameters, but, depending on the area, controller, and action passed in, it finds the correct route to use. Right now it is always using the top most route.